# Audio volume lowered after lock screen

Tags: release-hera, greeter, audio

I want to report a very weird thing I've noted on my laptop.

Basically, I set the volume to, let's say, max level because I'm watching a movie. Then I pause the movie, and get away from the pc for the time needed for the lock screen to activate.
I unlock the session and the volume is at 20% or 30%.

How is that possible that the audio volume level changes during lock screen without touching anything?

Answer (score 1):

similar issue here.

Before lockscreen the sound output is set to headset. After lockscreen it is changed to speakers. 
After each login I have to restore alsasound-settings:

```
alsactl --file xyz restore
```

I found some posts how to write a shell script to restore settings after login. But I couldn't test at the moment.

---

**Update**

Maybe this bash script could help:

```
gdbus monitor -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 | while read -r line; do
    if grep -q org.freedesktop.login1.Session.Unlock; then
        sleep 0.1
        sudo alsactl --file /Path/To/File/asound.state restore
    fi
done
```

On my system it needs the sleep time. Otherwise the script runs to early and "alsactl ... restore" does not work.

You can run it as a deamon, so you don't have to start manuelly.